# querying active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

i am trying to query my postgres db from rails with the following query

```
    def is_manager(team)
    User.where("manager <> 0 AND team_id == :team_id", {:team_id => team.id})
  end
```

this basically is checking that the manager is flagged and the that team.id is the current id passed into the function.

i have the following code in my view

```
 %td= is_manager(team)
```

error or what we are getting return is

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xa3ae51c>
```

any help on where i have gone wrong would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries to ActiveRecord always return ActiveRecord::Relations. Doing so essentially allows the lazy loading of queries. To understand why this is cool, consider this:

```
User.where(manager: 0).where(team_id: team_id).first
```

In this case, we get all users who aren't managers, and then we get all the non-manager users who are on team with id team_id, and then we select the first one. Executing this code will give you a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE manager = 0 AND team_id = X LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, even though there were multiple queries made in our code, ActiveRecord was able to squish all of that down into one query. This is done through the Relation. As soon as we need to actual object (i.e. when we call first), then ActiveRecord will go to the DB to get the records. This prevents unnecessary queries. ActiveRecord is able to do this because they return Relations, instead of the queried objects. The best way to think of the Relation class is that it is an instance of ActiveRecord with all the methods of an array. You can call queries on a relation, but you can also iterate over it.

Sorry if that isn't clear.

Oh, and to solve your problem. `%td = is_manager(team).to_a` This will convert the Relation object into an array of Users.

Comment: that query worked, though with the array, how do i access information from within it? ie say i wanted to extract the mangers name in a column called first_name?

Comment: `is_manager(team).map { |m| m.first_name }` will return an array of all the managers' names. You can also use the map shorthand which looks like: `is_manager(team).map(&:first_name)`.

Comment: next question i have Max, if i have the following `def full_name(user)
    "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
  end` and wanted to return the full_name without square brackets and inverted comma's what would be needed? as i tried `is_manager(team).map(&:full_name)` though it didnt work. thanks

Comment: The map method returns an array of results. If you directly print out the array, then you will get the square brackets and commas. If you want to print them out as a list in a view, you could do something like: https://gist.github.com/3274840

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve first record with .first, this might help.
**User.where("manager <> 0 AND team_id == :team_id", {:team_id => team.id}).first**

Comment: issue is there could be more than one manager allocated to a team, as i was hoping to be able to list them